# Pywin32: win32api.SendMessage to a DOS box program not possible?

Tags: winapi, pywin32, wscript.shell

Is it possible to use `win32api.SendMessage` to send characters to a program which seems to be running in some sort of DOS box?

In my Windows Task Manager I see a process called *ntvdm.exe* (apparently that is the "Virtual DOS Machine"). It looks like *wowexec.exe* (= "windows on windows") and my *target.exe* are both "inside" that *ntvdm.exe*, since they have no own PID in the Task Manager. Instead they are shown with an indent below *ntvdm.exe*.

I have tried to target **all** possible window handles for my *target.exe* (from parent = 0 down to every child) via `win32api.SendMessage(<mywindowhandle>, win32con.WM_CHAR, 0x41, 0)` but the 'A' never arrives in the program. `SendMessage` works in other programs, such as notepad and notepad++. Only the DOS program is causing me headaches.

Using `shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")` however in combination with `shell.AppAcitvate` (using the PID of *ntvdm.exe*) and `shell.SendKeys` works! Doesn't that send "WM_CHAR" messages in the background as well?

Answer (score 0):

In order to support a myriad of different application types, Windows NT has a fairly complex architecture. You're apparently assuming `WM_CHAR` messages are keystrokes. This is very much a Win16-way of thinking. The `WM` stands for Window Message; it's a keystroke event for applications with a window and a message pump.

Console programs on the other hand do not use window message pumps; they have Unix-style Standard In and Standard Out. `shell.sendKeys` understands the difference.

This also means a console program does not have a window handle. The PID is a process identifier, so not a window handle. A process can have 0, 1 or more window handles, so for every window handle there's a (generally non-unique) PID but not vice versa.

`SendKeys` works because the shell knows all this.